# spyOn not working with async pipe in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine

I have a simple component working well looking like that:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'component',
  template: `
    {{userWithAsyncPipe | async | json}} <!-- = null in test -->
    {{userFromOnInit | json}} <!-- working test -->
  `,
})
export class Component implements OnInit {
  constructor(private service: MyService) {
  }

  userWithAsyncPipe = this.service.getUser();
  userFromOnInit;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getUser().subscribe(user => this.userFromOnInit = user);
  }
}
```

I'm trying to test it by mocking the `service.getUser()` method. So I wrote a test component approximatly looking like this:

```
describe('', () => {

  ...
  let myService;
  beforeEach(() => {
    myService = TestBed.inject(MyService);
  });

  it('', () => {
    spyOn(myService, 'getUser').and.returnValue(of({name: 'Jacob'}));
  });
});
```

But when I look at the karma browser, only the variable `userFromOnInit` is resolved. `userWithAsyncPipe` is equal to `null`.

What the hell is that ?

Comment: could you add full testbed setup?

Comment: Also please take a look here, it has an example how to test similar code https://ng-mocks.sudo.eu/extra/mock-observables

Comment: I will try, but it's Angular, it involves a lot of code... Thanks for you exemple but it doesn't use | async pipe.

Comment: it shouldn't use it. the idea is that you provide a fake subject with `MockProvider` and `async` is provided by `CommonModule`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an example for you with [ng-mocks](https://ng-mocks.sudo.eu/extra/mock-observables)

https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-bas-is5zy?file=/src/test.spec.ts

```js
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import {
  Component,
  EventEmitter,
  Input,
  NgModule,
  Injectable,
  Output
} from "@angular/core";
import { MockBuilder, MockInstance, MockRender, ngMocks } from "ng-mocks";
import { EMPTY, Observable, of } from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
class MyService {
  getUser(): Observable<any> {
    return EMPTY;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: "app-target",
  template: `
    {{ userWithAsyncPipeFn() | async | json }}
    {{ userWithAsyncPipe | async | json }}
    {{ userFromOnInit | json }}
  `
})
class TargetComponent {
  userWithAsyncPipeFn = () => this.service.getUser();
  userWithAsyncPipe = this.service.getUser();
  userFromOnInit: any;

  constructor(private service: MyService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getUser().subscribe((user) => (this.userFromOnInit = user));
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  declarations: [TargetComponent],
  providers: [MyService]
})
class TargetModule {}
```

```js
describe("my sandbox", () => {
  beforeEach(() => MockBuilder(TargetComponent, TargetModule));

  it("should do something", () => {
    MockInstance(MyService, "getUser", () => of({ name: "Jacob" }));

    const fixture = MockRender(TargetComponent);
    expect(fixture.nativeElement.innerHTML.match(
      /\{\s*"name":\s*"Jacob"\s*\}/g
    ).length).toEqual(3);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. However is there anway to avoid installing a dependency ?

Comment: If you want to do it in `it`, you need properly configure TestBed in beforeEach, do not call `createComponent` anywhere, and then in `it` inject the service, mock it as you need, and only after it to call `createComponent` and `detectChanges`, in this case it should have the same effect as in the example above.

Comment: Wowww... Ok I understand why it wasn't working now. It makes sense. I can't understand why I didn't find this issue anywhere in the Web. Anyway, a huge thank to you  !